# Start Screen Background Size for Lumia 920

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, 8.1

The full screen resolution of a Lumia 920 is 768x1280. However, it appears the Start Screen backgrounds use a slightly different size - apparently, to give a bit of room for panning the image around as you scroll. What's the proper size for this image?

Comment: I think it will depends on how hight is your Start Screen.

Comment: no it doesn't. If you have more tiles on your screen, the background will just scroll slower.

Answer (score 2):

The proper background size for the Nokia Lumia 920 (768 x 1280) is 640 x 1280.

Comment: Do you have a source for that, or is that based on your own research?

Comment: shouldn't it be a bit higher (as in height) to leave room for the scrolling effect?

Comment: @RowlandShaw it is based on my own research. When the picture is bigger it wont be displayed for 100%.

Comment: @Thomas The background ratio is different because it is less wide. This ensures that the image is indeed longer (in height).

Comment: well if your Ratio is correct i'd propably go with 768 x 1536 just to not lose any Quality as 640 width would be stretched I guess.